# Confused about resolving of classname

Tags: clojure

two files

types.clj:

```
(ns test.types)

(defrecord Price [date price])
(defrecord ProductPrice [name prices])
```

core.clj (It's OK)

```
(ns test.core
  (:use [test.types])
  (:use [clojure.string :only (split)]))


(defn read-data [file]
  (let [name (subs (.getName file) 0 4)]
    (with-open [rdr (clojure.java.io/reader file)]
      (doall (map #(apply ->Price (split % #"\t")) (drop 2 (line-seq rdr)))))))
```

core.clj (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to resolve classname: ProductPrice)

```
(ns test.core
  (:use [test.types])
  (:use [clojure.string :only (split)]))


(defn read-data [file]
  (let [name (subs (.getName file) 0 4)]
    (with-open [rdr (clojure.java.io/reader file)]
      (ProductPrice. name (doall (map #(apply ->Price (split % #"\t")) (drop 2 (line-seq rdr))))))))
```

core.clj (It's OK)

```
(ns test.core
  (:use [test.types])
  (:use [clojure.string :only (split)]))

(defrecord tProductPrice [name prices])
(defn read-data [file]
  (let [name (subs (.getName file) 0 4)]
    (with-open [rdr (clojure.java.io/reader file)]
      (tProductPrice. name (doall (map #(apply ->Price (split % #"\t")) (drop 2 (line-seq rdr)))))))
```

core.clj (java.lang.IllegalStateException: ->ProductPrice already refers to: #'test.types/->ProductPrice in namespace: test.core)

```
(ns test.core
  (:use [test.types])
  (:use [clojure.string :only (split)]))

(defrecord ProductPrice [name prices])
(defn read-data [file]
  (let [name (subs (.getName file) 0 4)]
    (with-open [rdr (clojure.java.io/reader file)]
      (ProductPrice. name (doall (map #(apply ->Price (split % #"\t")) (drop 2 (line-seq rdr)))))))
```

I totally confused about these exceptions. And I can't find any more usage about 'record' except some simplest examples from clojure.org and books.

Any help, Thank you very much!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

defrecord  creates a java class in the package named after the current namespace. (ProductPrice. ...) is a call to the constructor of that type; this is java interop - not a plain function call.

You cannot refer to a class defined outside of java.lang or the current namespace unless you explicitly **import** it or specify the full package name. This includes calling its constructor.

So, to fix the problem you need to import Price and ProductPrice.

```
 (ns test.core (:import [test.types Price]))
 (Price. ...)
```

or call the full class+package name:

```
 (test.types.Price. ...)
```

Comment: Note that hyphen / underscore mangling in namespace names causes confusion here. If you ``defrecord`` something in ``clj-test`` namespace it will create a class in ``clj_test`` package and your ``:import`` will need to reflect this

Comment: @Joost Diepenmaat Thanks! Why `->Price` can be used without import? And 'import' seems not work for me, still "java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: test.types.ProductPrice"

Comment: ->Price is an additionally generated helper function which is a real clojure function, and so exported when you `use` the package. Also, you need to make sure the record types are compiled (`use` or `require` the namespace they're defined in) before you can `import` them. If you can't get that to work, please create a new question  with example code.

Comment: @JoostDiepenmaat, you should probably add what you wrote in your comment (`Also, you need to make sure the record types are compiled (use or require the namespace they're defined in) before you can import them`) to your answer; for a `clojure` noob like me, it was life saving!